# sqli and database connection problems?

Tags: php, mysql

I have my PHP as following. These are two files in total

For 'dbh.php':

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$name = "login_system";

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","","login_system");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


?>
```

For 'index3.php':

```
<?php 
    include'dbh.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> It is index 3</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        global $con;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users;"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql );
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($resultCheck > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(result)){
                echo $row['useruid'] . "<br>";
            }
        }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

I got errors for executing this.

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phplesson\index3.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phplesson\index3.php on line 14
```

Do this mean I get connection problems ? or other problems else?

Also, how can I fix it?

Appreciate for help!!

Comment: Why you define constants for server, username, ... But use the values in connect?

Comment: at first, i haven't added global $con but this will cause another error: the undefined variable of $con

Comment: The define constants are just for comment. The values should be correct

Comment: @Jens Why do you think that would make a difference. `global` doesn't do anything unless it's in a function.

Comment: `dbh.php` should call `die()` if the connection fails, so that `index3.php` doesn't try to use the failed connection.

Comment: i have tried to use var_dump($con) to check, the result is null. Does it mean i get something wrong with my database connection?

Comment: Appreciate! I fix my error. All are because of database connection. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Replace code of "dbh.php" by below:

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "testc";
$con = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$db_name);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Replace code of "index3.php" by below:

```
<?php 
    include'db.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> It is index 3</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users;"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo $row['useruid'] . "<br>";
            }
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your helps. I have tried your codes but there is still error.

Comment: Therefore i use var_dump to check $con . I find it output null. Do I get sth wrong about my connection?

Comment: Appreciate! I fix my error. All are because of database connection. Thank you very much.